# jQuery is undefined on page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, undefined, page-refresh

I don't think this issue has been raised anywhere else but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm using a beautiful piece of javascript code that I found on the net for adding an image slideshow on a page. I've added it to an ASP.NET page and it works fine, the images are displayed correctly at the appropriate intervals. However, the problem is that whenever I refresh the page (F5 or the 'refresh' button on the address bar, I'm testing on IE9, by the way), this error message appears: 
    Line: 17 
    Error: 'jQuery' is undefined

followed by: 
    Line:44 
    Error: The value of the property 'jQuery' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

When I go to another page and click the Back button, the slideshow also works perfectly. It seems that the problem only occurs on page refresh.

Here is the code within the ASP header content tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fadeslideshow.js"></script>
```

The code for the slideshow has been taken from "Dynamic Drive" (Ultimate Fade In Slideshow v2.0) http://www.dynamicdrive.com/

I've tried moving the javascript references to the bottom section within the ASP body content tags just in case the error has something to do with the order in which the javascript is being called when the page load. Although I really have little idea and am a bit stuck at the moment. Any help is appreciated.

Code for ASP.NET page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Community Support" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Copy of CommunitySupport.aspx.vb" Inherits="CommunitySupport" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fadeslideshow.js">

    /***********************************************
    * Ultimate Fade In Slideshow v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
    * This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
    * Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
    ***********************************************/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var defaultPhoto1 = new String("");
    var defaultPhoto2 = new String("");
    var defaultCaption1 = new String("");
    var defaultCaption2 = new String("");

    defaultCaption1 = "caption A";
    defaultCaption2 = "caption B";

    defaultPhoto1 = "Images/photo1.png";
    defaultPhoto2 = "Images/photo2.png";

    function getSlideShowImages() {

                var mygallery = new fadeSlideShow({
                wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
                dimensions: [320, 220], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
                imagearray: [
                [defaultPhoto1, "", "", defaultCaption1],
                [defaultPhoto2, "", "", defaultCaption2]

            ] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
            ,
                displaymode: { type: 'auto', pause: 2500, cycles: 0, wraparound: false },
                persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
                fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
                descreveal: "ondemand",
                togglerid: ""
            })            
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidSlideShow" runat="server"/>            
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidCaptions" runat="server"/>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="60%" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" valign="bottom" class="heading1">Title
                            </td>                                                            
                        </tr>                              
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%"><br />Content
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>                                
                        </tr>
                    </table>
        </td>
        <td width="40%" valign="top">
            <div id="fadeshow1" class="slideDiv">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The "fadeshow1" div is where the slideshow is being displayed.

Comment: Could you perchance link the page in question?

Comment: showing a bit more code would help, as we don't know how you're calling the actual script on line 44

Comment: Could you show us some of the html code that surrounds the JQuery script include?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your jQuery ver. 1.4.2 library script reference. You need to reference the jquery library correctly in your ASP header content settings from

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.42./jquery.min.js"
```

to:

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
```

I'm also noticing that you are missing the terminating semi-colon each time you initialize your `fadeSlideShow` object:

```
var mygallery = new fadeSlideShow({
            wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
            dimensions: [320, 220], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
            imagearray: [
            [imageArray[0], imageArray[0], "_new", captionArray[0]],
            [imageArray[1], imageArray[1], "_new", captionArray[1]],
            [imageArray[2], imageArray[2], "_new", captionArray[2]],
            [imageArray[3], imageArray[3], "_new", captionArray[3]]

        ] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
        ,
            displaymode: { type: 'auto', pause: 2500, cycles: 0, wraparound: false },
            persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
            fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
            descreveal: "ondemand",
            togglerid: ""
        }); //<-- semi-colon here
```

Don't forget to clear your browser cache after making the changes.

Comment: OK. Thanks, chridam. I must've switched them around. But this doesn't seem to be the real cause of my problem though. I'll just change the code above...

Comment: Cool, does the problem persist even after correctly referencing the library, i.e. clearing your browser cache and/or page refresh?

Comment: With the correct library reference in place, the page works fine on page load. The problem only persists on page refresh. What happens is that the error message appears (jQuery is undefined) and then the slideshow is not visible anymore.

Comment: Thanks, frosty. Can you please explain a bit further though. Not exactly sure about "ready" method for ASP.NET...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the semi-colons and clearing your broswer cache after the changes

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to put the function inside an "ready" function. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getSlideShowImages();
});
```

Comment: what i mentioned above. Holds true. But you haven't actually included the code that calls "jQuery". if my suggested doesn't work 1) post all of the code. Just the output. We don't need to know about the vb part. 2) also double check if your using third party plugin they support the correct version of jquery.

Comment: I tried putting this within the script tags in the ASPX page. It this correct? It wouldn't work though. I'll post the code...

Comment: i think you might be tangled up in version issues. i looked at the lib website and they are using an older jquery. Try this. Copy your page and get it working without your vb additions. And then slowly add your changes. The issue is "JQuery" is not defined. But we don't see this in  your code examples.So there is something elsewhere causing this.

Comment: Thank you frosty. I've been doing the coding on a separate computer with the Internet connection turned off. When I turned it on, the slideshow now executes without any issues on page refresh as well. Internet connection - one silly little fault. Thanks to all the responses though.

Comment: Turns out that the error message is due to a small problem: the internet connection is turned off. This newbie has learnt yet another lesson: when testing anything to do with jQuery, make sure that you're connected to the internet. At the moment, everything works fine, the slideshow now loads on page refresh and no error messages appear. Thank you to everyone's responses though; they're all greatly appreciated. (Being a newbie also means that I cannot post the answer to my own question within 8 hours so I'll just post this as a comment...)

Comment: you should install firebug. or make friends with chrome developer. It is essential to use a tool like these when developer js.